# Viewport shading and gizmos dissapeared after 4.0

Tags: 3d-view, interface, object-mode

In the layout tab, object mode and edit doesn't show the viewport shading, gizmo and overlays.
[image: object mode, layout, no controls]
Sculpt mode works just fine.
[image: sculpt mode works just fine]
I don't know what or why happened.
It started after i updated to 4.0, still going on in 4.0.1
No problems with previous 3.6.4 version.
Couldn't find and solution in windows tab, closed all the addons and i'm countering the same thing.

Comment: Can you try adding another Layout workspace by clicking the + icon at the right-hand end of the workspaces toolbar then selecting it from the General menu that pops up? If it brings them back you can then right-click on the original one and delete it then right-click the new one and select Reorder to Front.

Comment: Ty for the suggestion, I've tried this but nothing happens.
It's interesting as I don't have this on my laptop, i've updated them both but this issue is spesific to my desktop workstation.

Comment: Unfortunately you're not the only one to report this. It appears to be a bug but has only affected a few people. See [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/305970/blender-4-0-1-topright-toolbar-missing#305970) posting from today! :^(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i seem to find the solution, kind of.
It was retopoflow causing this issue for me, loading back to factory settings brought back everything.